# Alternative of href="#" retaining mouseover properties

Tags: javascript, css, href

I have a long HTML page, on modal open the page scrolls to top which can be solved by removing href="#" from

```
<a href="#" id="myId">Click me to open modal</a>
```

But removing that, it changes mouseover display of "hand" on anchor tag to "text blinker".

How do I get rid of `href="#"` without loosing that property?

Answer (score 8):

Set

```
cursor:pointer;
```

on the `<a>` element

Comment: … and use a button instead of an anchor without an href.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1:

Instead of:

```
<a href="#" id="myId">Click me to open modal</a>
```

Try:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="myId">Click me to open modal</a>
```

This will treat the `<a>` tag as a proper anchor, with default CSS styles, but will not execute the default link behavior that causes the browser to scroll to the top.

### Option 2:

Use `event.preventDefault()` in your javascript to prevent the browser from scrolling to the top.

### Option 3:

Remove the `href` property altogether, and add `cursor: pointer` to your CSS.

Comment: @GiacomoPaita I generally agree, but in cases like this with a modal window there isn't always a semantically appropriate target nor a reason to store a URL route in the browser's history.

Comment: thank you for the detailed description, cleared a lot of things for me along with providing other options that I can use

Comment: No problem. There's lots more on the topic. If you're interested, here's [another StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0?rq=1) that dives much deeper into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the anchor default behavior, setting `event.preventDefault()` in your JS.

I don't know how your code is, but here is a jQuery [example](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
<a href="http://jquery.com">default click action is prevented</a>
<div id="log"></div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
 $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $( "<div>" )
     .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
     .appendTo( "#log" );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a blank link use the URL: "about:blank"